# Unable to install distribute with python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, distribute

```
pip install --upgrade distribute
```

throws the following error.

```
Downloading/unpacking distribute from http://pypi.python.org/packages/sourc
e/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.25.tar.gz#md5=a690874b9964d958a3200485eb827b1
d
  Running setup.py egg_info for package distribute
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
      File "setuptools\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
      File "setuptools\extension.py", line 2, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
      File "setuptools\dist.py", line 103
        except ValueError, e:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>

  File "setuptools\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>

    from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library

  File "setuptools\extension.py", line 2, in <module>

    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched

  File "setuptools\dist.py", line 103

    except ValueError, e:

                     ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your version of pip isn't compatible with Python 3. Run

```
pip --version
```

and if the version is < 1.1, try updating pip first.

Update: apparently it's a known [issue](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/issue/268/installing-distribute-with-pip-32-u-fails) with distribute.

Comment: c:\Python32\Scripts\pip.exe --version
pip 1.1.post1 from c:\python32\lib\site-packages\pip-1.1.post1-py3.2.egg (python 3.2)

Comment: Apparently it's a known issue: https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/issue/268/installing-distribute-with-pip-32-u-fails

Comment: distribute-0.7.3 doesn't have this problem anymore.